# mongodb 4.0.1 ECONNREFUSED Works in node.js on dev computer

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a personal AWS server running MongoDB 4.0.1 and Docker version 17.03.2-ce, build f5ec1e2
I just got the latest version of node.js (10.9)

I can connect, view and edit documents on MongoDB using Compass.

When I run my node.js on my dev computer, I can use postman to get and post.
When I build a docker container and run it on the AWS docker postman returns ECONNREFUSED.

```
//index.js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

// set up express app
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//initialize routes  - set router to 
app.use('/database', require('./routes/recipes'));    

// listen for requests
const PORT = 4000;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
app.listen(PORT, HOST, function () {
    console.log('now listening for requests');
});


//recipes.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const MongoClient = require('mongodb');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
//const url = 'mongodb://localhost/local';

// get a list of recipes
router.get('/recipes', function (req, res) {
...
```

Comment: something to dowith proxy?

Comment: Did you already try to replace localhost with the name of your mongdb container for the in-docker solution? Using localhost inside a container will point to the localhost of the container instead of the localhost of your host server.

Comment: Yes, at first I used the mondodb://MyWebsite.us:27017 and I got a different error.  Or is there a different name you meant?   recipes is the name on the image and docker I am using

Comment: I am not doing anything I know of with proxies.  I am a noob at linux.

Answer (score 1):

replace localhost with the AWS ***PRIVATE*** IP address, not the public one or the public url.

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';